# AWS Cloud 9 Terminal Freezing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, cloud9-ide

I'm doing the [Learning Enough Ruby on Rails to be Dangerous](https://www.learnenough.com) Tutorial. Per instructions (10.2.3 Friendly Forwarding exercise 2), I put a **debugger** statement in the Sessions **controller** and attempted to visit a route that requires a user to be authenticated and authorized. When I enter the url the debugger is triggered, however it **freezes the terminal** so I **cannot exit the rails console**. Next, I tried to close the terminal, close all files, closing the Cloud9 IDE browser tab and log out of AWS. Unfortunately the IDE didn't shut down and logging back in to the AWS console resulted in the same frozen terminal. After a couple of hours and the terminal and IDE successfully shut down and was usable.

Is there another way to reset the Cloud9 IDE?

Comment: What do you mean it freezes the terminal? Doesn't it advance by pressing c?